# Output CURL in Ruby

Tags: ruby, curl, httprequest

I want to create a CURL call when running my program. I currently have a script, and I would like to output a similar CURL call to the console. Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
       puts "curl -v -H \" myToken: #{request["Token"]}\"" 
        callData['HEADER'].each do |hKey, hVal|
            request[hKey] = hVal
            puts "-H\"#{hKey} : #{hVal}\""
        end
        puts "\"#{callData['URL']}\""
```

This is my output:

```
curl -v -H " Authorization BEARER FB4GGY5CRhL1lc5a2QIZQw"
"http://mysite/folder/file?myId=abc123&date=2013-02-28&unique=1052946"
```

The problem is that the URL is on a new line. How would I get everything on one line so I can could copy and paste into terminal to make a CURL call, while still being able to account for the dynamic number of headers in my call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `print` instead of `puts`, and then, do a `puts` at the end without any argument to ensure a line end.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for! Thank you! I'll accept ASAP. Great answer btw!